# I need to replace white space and special characters from within magento2 var/import/images folder

Tags: magento, magento2

I have hundreds of images imported into var/import/images folder that have special characters and white spaces in them I need the special characters removed and white spaces replaced with a dash.

I need the following

1. replace white spaces with a dash
2. remove (
3. remove )
4. remove '

file types are png and jpg

images are on remote server

Answer (score 1):

Create a `renamer.php` file with the following content:

```php
<?php
foreach (glob('*[_\'\(\)\ ]*.{png,jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
    $newName = str_replace(' ', '-', $filename);
    $newName = preg_replace('/[\(\)\']/', '', $newName);
    echo "mv \"$filename\" " . $newName . PHP_EOL;
//    rename($filename, $newName);
}
```

Save the file in var/import/images and then 
Run `php -f renamer.php`.

It will output the commands to rename the files, like this:

```
$ php -f renamer.php 
mv "d'pool.png" dpool.png
mv "foo(bar).png" foobar.png
mv "hello_.png" hello_.png
mv "hello_world.png" hello_world.png
mv "hi world.png" hi-world.png
```

If you want it to rename the files for you, just uncomment the last line.